# Append more than 2 data frames in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have about 25 data frames with identical column headers that I need to append to one another. I've tried this in the past using 24 .append() calls but it didn't work. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What didn't work, exactly?

Comment: The number of rows was erratic. Unfortunately I don't have the data with me anymore, just sad memories, but imagine 4 data frames with 1000 rows. Merge 1 results in 2000 rows, merge 2 results in 2700 rows, merge 3 results in 3892 rows... it was weird

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html, and the picture there is also very illustrative, 
copy the code here,

```
frames = [df1, df2, df3]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Comment: Question was on `append`, not `concat`